# find UPN's from email address Powershell / AAD

Tags: powershell

Powershell noob here trying to get a list of UPN's from AAD using only a csv with email address and failing any help pointing me in the correct direction;

[Example CSV extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSkL3.png)

I can obtain the UPN from a single email address using this code;

```
$User = "email@example.com"

Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(Mail,'$User')" | Select-Object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Mail,ObjectId | Export-csv -append -notypeinformation “C:\Temp\output.csv”
```

My attempt to do this for multiple email addresses in a csv fails here is what i have so far;

```
$Result = @()
 
$AllUsers = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Users.csv"
 
ForEach ($User in $AllUsers)
{
    Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(Mail,'$Users')" | Select-Object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Mail,ObjectId
 
$Result += New-Object PSObject -property $([ordered]@{
UserName = $User.DisplayName
UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
PrimarySmtpAddress = $User.Mail
AliasSmtpAddresses = ($User.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike 'smtp:*'} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'smtp:',''}) -join ','
UserId= $User.ObjectId
})
}

$Result | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

any suggestions where i am failing in the above or recommendations on how to do this better?

Comment: Single Column of email addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is in your filter, `"startswith(Mail,'$Users')"`, in this case `$Users` is not defined.

Next issue is, [`Get-AzureADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) is being called but it's output is not being captured.

This should work, I'm assuming the Csv column having the user's emails is called **EmailAddress**, change `(Import-Csv ...).EmailAddress` for the corresponding property Name.

```
# for each value in the "EmailAddress" Column
(Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Users.csv").EmailAddress | ForEach-Object {
    # if the user exists in Azure AD
    if($azusr = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "mail eq '$_'") {
        # output this object
        [pscustomobject]@{
            UserName           = $azusr.DisplayName
            UserPrincipalName  = $azusr.UserPrincipalName
            PrimarySmtpAddress = $azusr.Mail
            AliasSmtpAddresses = $azusr.ProxyAddresses -clike 'smtp:*' -replace 'smtp:' -join ','
            UserId             = $azusr.ObjectId
        }
    }
 } | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you so very much from a Powershell noob